# typeorm use existing sql view

Tags: javascript, mariadb, typeorm

I've already generated a view in my MariaDB that I want to get data from.

So far I haven't seen anyone use their existing views, rather reimplementing them with a View Entity.

My query is quite complex and I was wondering if I could use it as is.

Comment: How do you get data from regular base tables? Do the same here.

Comment: @jarlh I cannot do that since the view doesn't have a PK

Answer (score 1):

Just creating a view entry to get data from a view seems to work:

```js
import {ViewColumn, ViewEntity} from "typeorm";

@ViewEntity({
    expression: `select * from v_best_unspecific_bot`
})
export class BestUnspecificBot {

    @ViewColumn()
    id!: string

    @ViewColumn()
    authcookie!: string

}
```